# Cannot run rake test Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm following Rails Tutorials by Michael Hartl ([chapter 3](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages)). However, when I edit the **Gemfile** like he did and then run rake test, rails suggested me to put this line : `config.web_console.development_only = false` 
in the **application config** file. I did that and run `bundle exec rake test` again, here's the error message:

```
/home/ys/workspace/sample_app/db/schema.rb doesn't exist yet. Run `rake db:migrate` to create it, then try again. If you do not intend to use a database, you should instead alter /home/ys/workspace/sample_app/config/application.rb to limit the frameworks that will be loaded.
/home/ys/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': cannot load such file -- guard (LoadError)
    from /home/ys/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /home/ys/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/ys/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /home/ys/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-minitest-2.4.4/lib/minitest/guard_minitest_plugin.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ys/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /home/ys/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /home/ys/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/ys/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /home/ys/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minitest-5.8.4/lib/minitest.rb:91:in `block in load_plugins'
    from /home/ys/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minitest-5.8.4/lib/minitest.rb:85:in `each'
    from /home/ys/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minitest-5.8.4/lib/minitest.rb:85:in `load_plugins'
    from /home/ys/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minitest-5.8.4/lib/minitest.rb:114:in `run'
    from /home/ys/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minitest-5.8.4/lib/minitest.rb:56:in `block in autorun'
```

I then proceeded to `rake db:migrate`, then run rake test again:

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 15638
/home/ys/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': cannot load such file -- guard (LoadError)
    from /home/ys/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /home/ys/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/ys/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /home/ys/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-minitest-2.4.4/lib/minitest/guard_minitest_plugin.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ys/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /home/ys/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /home/ys/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/ys/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /home/ys/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minitest-5.8.4/lib/minitest.rb:91:in `block in load_plugins'
    from /home/ys/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minitest-5.8.4/lib/minitest.rb:85:in `each'
    from /home/ys/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minitest-5.8.4/lib/minitest.rb:85:in `load_plugins'
    from /home/ys/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minitest-5.8.4/lib/minitest.rb:114:in `run'
    from /home/ys/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minitest-5.8.4/lib/minitest.rb:56:in `block in autorun'
```

All I can guess is that there is something wrong with Ruby because I upgraded from 2.3.0 to 2.3.1 the other day as rails console complained about buggy, old version when I run `bundle install`.
So, How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/guard/guard-minitest

Add the guard gem to your gem file.
gem 'guard'

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this might work:

> 1) Just remove guard-spring from your Gemfile and Guardfile.
>
> 2) Then upgrade guard-rspec (run bundle update guard-rspec)
>
> 3) Setup
>   guard-rspec to use spring (see this:
>   https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec#options)

From: https://github.com/guard/guard/issues/734

Comment: OMG I simply remove gem 'guard-minitest' and it works

Comment: @JoelBrewer so why does removing guard-spring works fine? I am following same tutorial, but did not face any such issue.

Comment: @Nirupa "guard-spring is not updated to work with newer versions of Guard, but it's not even necessary anymore, since guard-rspec supports spring."

Comment: @Nirupa you also follow that tutorial? Weird...why did I face such issue